# GDAL on Windows Server

Tags: gdal

I develop a C# app (asp.net core) that uses the nuget package MaxRev.Gdal.Core (v.3.3.3).
When the code execute on the server (Windows server 2019) I get this error

**PROJ: pj_obj_create: Cannot find proj.db**

I'm not sure to fully understand what I should be doing. Do I need to install anything on the server first?

==========UPDATE===========

I could make it work on the server by copying the content of the local folder "**\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\gdal\share**" to the folder on the server "**\runtimes\win-x64\native\maxrev.gdal.core.libshared**". (I had to create the maxrev.gdal.core.libshared folder).
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Your system should have an environmental variable PROJ_LIB set to point to a directory that holds data that the coordinate transformation library Proj needs, including the file proj.db.

Comment: Thanks. In local, I can see the location of proj.db in \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\gdal\share
But I can't see it in the destination folder when I "publish" my project. Is that helping?

Comment: Did you try se edit the PROJ_LIB env, or set it if it was missing?

Answer (score 0):

I could it make work with the package MaxRev.Gdal.WindowsRuntime.Minimal. I was using the package MaxRev.Gdal.Core. And I don't have to call GdalBase.ConfigureAll() with the latest.